# How to trap errors in vb .net?

Tags: vb.net, exception

I have a load of experience with VBA and am just learning VB .net. I've written a backup utility which works fine until if finds a file that is locked.  At this point it throws an exception:

> System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file.

The line in question is

```
 FromFile.CopyTo(ToFileName, True)
```

With VBA I could simply trap the error and resume next. It looks like I need a "Try Catch finally" section, but have no idea how to  identify this exception, and tell the program to carry on. It is a desktop application based round a form.

Answer (score 2):

You can just wrap your command in a `Try .. Catch` block:

```
    Try
        FromFile.CopyTo(ToFileName, True)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Handle the exception (if you want to)
    End Try
```

In this example all the details about the exception will be contained in the object `ex`. You don't have to have any code in the `Catch` section - left empty you are effectively saying ignore all errors (normally a bad thing to do).

You only need a finally section if you want to run some code all the time (whether the code in your Try worked or not):

```
    Try
        FromFile.CopyTo(ToFileName, True)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Handle the exception (if you want to)
    Finally
        ' This will execute whether there was an exception or not
    End Try
```

You can also catch specific exception types and handle them differently if you want to:

```
Try
    FromFile.CopyTo(ToFileName, True)
Catch ioEx as IO.IOException
    ' Code in this section will only be executed if an exception of type 'IO.IOException' is thrown
Catch nullEx As ArgumentNullException
    ' Handle a null argument exception
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

That was a great help. Thanks:
Here's what I now have as a solution:

```
        Try
            FromFile.CopyTo(ToFileName, True)

        Catch ex As System.IO.IOException
            If ex.HResult = -2147024863 Or ex.HResult = -2147024864 Then
            Else
                MsgBox(ex.HResult & " - " & ex.Message)
            End If

        End Try
```

I next need to think about what to do with other exceptions, but that can wait a while.

Next step is to count the number of files looked at, and the number actually copied as a grand total across all the subfolders

Comment: FYI for file operations, you might also get `System.Security.SecurityException` or `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

Comment: @dmhzx What do the braces do?

Comment: @mary: I was having trouble putting 'code' wrappers for the post. The braces don't actually do anything. They aren't in the program at all. Sorry about that